# What are the resistors in digital pots?

Tags: resistors, fet

Do they place tiny switches with passive resistors or are they using fets in the ohmic region ?

Comment: Any particular digipot? The exact mechanism varies between manufacturers (and even implementations within the same manufacturer).

Comment: I dont have a particular digipot. Just a general question.

Comment: Some use a 256 fets/resistors per switch; others use an R-2R network

Comment: @Andyaka: Do you have any datasheet links for things that call themselves digipots but don't use a bunch of discrete resistors in series?  I don't recall having heard of such?

Comment: @supercat TBH I have used them but didn't care what they used inside - I was only interested in their temeperature coefficient for the one particular project and they were OK. I suspect they use an R-2R network like dacs but I don't really know. To me it's like "what's under the bonnet/hood" - don't care - just interested in top speed, acceleration and fule economy LOL.

Comment: @Andyaka: Digipots are often used in situations where it's important that changes to the pot position not affect the overall resistance.  I'm not sure what sort of R/2R circuit topology would work with that.

Comment: @supercat only used them once and they did the job (last year) - in fact they worked as a variable gain amplifier very well, but, I did spend a lot of time choosing the right one. I'm sure there must be googlinfo available that spills the beans.

Comment: @supercat are you saying that R/2R is uncommon ?

Comment: @efox29: R2R is common for digital-to-analog convertors, but the amount of current passed from the positive reference to the negative reference will vary depending upon the value being output.  A digi-pot, by contrast, will have a constant resistance between the positive and negative reference terminals.

Comment: @supercat I'm going to wildly speculate that some digital pots might use two R2R DACs in series with the common point being the wiper. DAC1 at full scale means DAC2 at zero and vice versa between the two extremes. I'm proposing this because, to me, DAC tech has been around years and each DAC only will use 8 FETs/analoge switches with its own R2R network. This means that for an 8 bit digipot, instead of 256 switches only 16 are required. On the other hand if you look up multiplying DACs these give you, in effect, a digital pot.

Comment: @Andyaka: In R/2R DAC, the resistance RH between the high-side and the output, and the resistance RL between the low-side and the output, will be such that (1/RH+1/RL) is a constant.  In a digipot, RH+RL will be a constant.  The fomer situation is more useful when the device is driven by a low-impedance source and drives a medium-impedance load; the latter is more useful when the device is driven by a medium-impedance load and drives a high-impedance load.

Comment: @Andyaka: I posted as an answer a circuit which illustrates why an R/2R DAC would be suitable for some digi-pot applications but grossly unsuitable for others.

Answer (score 1):

I think anything called a digi-pot will have to use cascaded resistors.  An R/2R topology has the effect of yielding a constant *output* impedance when driven with a low-impedance source, but its *input* impedance will vary depending upon the value selected.  The circuit below illustrates a 4-bit R/2R DAC with source and load impedance switched between 1K and zero/infinite (it runs a 0-15 cycle with each combination of source/load impedance).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fleg7p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When source impedance is zero and load impedance is infinite, the output ramps 0 to 15/16 volts.  Adding a 1K load (closing RLY6) cuts the output voltage, but it still ramps nicely.  When the source resistance is increased to 1K (RLY5 opens), however, the ramp becomes not only non-linear, but non-monotonic.

While it would probably be possible to construct a digipot with two sets of eight switched resistors in a 1:2:4:8:16:32:64:128 sequence, I'm not sure that would be particularly helpful from a cost perspective since ensuring that the 128:1 ratio remains 128:1 over various temperature conditions would likely mean that the larger resistor had to be constructed out of 128 smaller ones wired in series.

An approach that might be somewhat workable would be to have e.g. 65 unit resistors and a circuit which connects between two spots two-resistors apart a series of four pairs of two parallel resistors.  The smaller network would have a series resistance of 2R, and it would sit across two resistors totalling 2R, thus yielding a net resistance of 1R.  Moving the taps would cause slight momentary increase or decrease in the outer resistance (depending upon make or break behavior) but not nearly as disastrous as with R/2R DAC.  I don't know if anyone uses such an approach, however.

Comment: Interesting dude +1